# Math.random and decimals

Tags: java, random

I really want to understand, thx for help.
I've been watching Derek Banas Java Programming video and I got stuck to this:

int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 126) + 1;

The goal is to get a random number from 1 to 126 included.
It works but why? How can it output 126?

- If casting int drop decimals.

  > 126included125(See testing)
- If Math.random() returns 0 - 0.9 inclusive.

The nearest would be like:

1. int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 126) + 1;
2. int randomNumber = (int) (0.99 * 126) + 1;
3. int randomNumber = (int) (124.74) + 1;
4. int randomNumber = (int) 125.74;
5. int randomNumber = 125;

Can someone explain to me why Im wrong.

Testing:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random_Number_Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        boolean Program_On_Going = true;
        double RoundTest = 125.74;

        while(Program_On_Going)
        {
            int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 126) + 1;

            if(randomNumber == 126)
            {
                System.out.print(randomNumber);
                System.out.print("included");
                Program_On_Going = false;

                System.out.print((int) RoundTest);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results

> 18
>   30
>   101
>   77
>   101
>   85
>   87
>   6
>   89
>   26
>   20
>   115
>   108
>   13
>   53
>   30
>   85
>   108
>   41
>   110
>   22
>   3
>   38
>   106
>   46
>   102
>   117
>   95
>   36
>   44
>   65
>   87
>   87
>   4
>   114
>   70
>   8
>   120
>   50
>   28
>   60
>   97
>   101
>   25
>   30
>   96
>   4
>   105
>   55
>   29
>   20
>   77
>   105
>   91
>   19
>   81
>   105
>   66
>   1
>   78
>   81
>   48
>   77
>   82
>   11
>   68
>   113
>   1
>   7
>   90
>   104
>   96
>   100
>   70
>   114
>   14
>   125
>   42
>   108
>   16
>   119
>   103
>   70
>   84
>   83
>   42
>   15
>   102
>   45
>   69
>   80
>   123
>   56
>   39
>   115
>   88
>   70
>   111
>   30
>   68
>   19
>   34
>   17
>   24
>   71
>   107
>   81
>   76
>   42
>   80
>   123
>   19
>   54
>   47
>   96
>   58
>   64
>   52
>   61
>   117
>   64
>   103
>   47
>   40
>   60
>   35
>   23
>   90
>   75
>   91
>   29
>   16
>   7
>   15
>   20
>   50
>   85
>   72
>   109
>   85
>   108
>   47
>   54
>   79
>   91
>   102
>   84
>   101
>   5
>   17
>   50
>   115
>   115
>   71
>   67
>   83
>   15
>   99
>   77
>   101
>   20
>   79
>   22
>   25
>   30
>   108
>   46
>   75
>   89
>   80
>   103
>   51
>   61
>   15
>   91
>   9
>   61
>   90
>   11
>   5
>   27
>   36
>   116
>   15
>   14
>   105
>   5
>   95
>   53
>   97
>   55
>   59
>   1
>   81
>   97
>   109
>   77
>   37
>   3
>   84
>   115
>   87
>   15
>   40
>   93
>   61
>   68
>   14
>   93
>   15
>   38
>   55
>   15
>   72
>   48
>   103
>   75
>   42
>   63
>   64
>   61
>   114
>   103
>   17
>   47
>   31
>   102
>   56
>   57
>   113
>   82
>   85
>   48
>   1
>   120
>   117
>   25
>   77
>   101
>   19
>   84
>   54
>   101
>   102
>   2
>   14
>   114
>   105
>   20
>   57
>   70
>   94
>   7
>   27
>   123
>   108
>   109
>   47
>   4
>   28
>   72
>   49
>   86
>   84
>   64
>   86
>   71
>   69
>   33
>   110
>   109
>   19
>   71
>   92
>   49
>   50
>   77
>   29
>   31
>   55
>   62
>   75
>   61
>   8
>   52
>   115
>   69
>   39
>   71
>   107
>   42
>   57
>   92
>   88
>   56
>   88
>   89
>   7
>   123
>   49
>   13
>   107
>   6
>   99
>   21
>   29
>   49
>   3
>   82
>   60
>   104
>   70
>   123
>   91
>   4
>   14
>   57
>   63
>   27
>   126included125

Comment: Your random link is about javascript, not java.

Comment: Math.random() generates a number between 0.0 - 0.9 inclusive. "1" is not generated by the Math.random().

Comment: Your output **includes** "126included125". And `125` + `1` is `126` (which is why it is included).

Comment: it cant reach 125 cause .99 * 126 = 124.74

Comment: @Mark it doesn't stop at `.99`. For Example, you could get `0.9920634920634921`, which indeed gives 125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [Math#random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) states

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

Thus, the returned value could have up to `16` decimal places. An Example for your case would be

```
(0.9920634920634921 * 126) + 1
125 + 1
126
```

Comment: Okay that's why, I though it was one of those situation where the result can never reach the value but can be very close to it. Thanks you. I should revise my math.

Comment: It is a situation where the result can never reach the value, the value is 126 not 125. thx again

Answer (score 1):

The thing is Math.random() does not return just 0.99 but it returns 0.999999999

0.99999999 * 125 = 125.9999874

125.9999874  + 1 = 126.9999874

int randomNumber = (int) 126.9999874 ;

int randomNumber = 126;